# How to do group by items and sum quantity of items in text file

Tags: c#

I have for example this text file:

```
SKU;QTY
SKU_1;1
SKU_2;2
SKU_1;2
```

I am trying to sum up the quantities for each item using the SKU. The above file when parsed should output the below content in another text file:

```
SKU;QTY
SKU_1;3
SKU_2;2
```

How would I go about starting this?

Comment: Welcome!  Any code to show?  Sadly SO is not a _code-writing service_. [ask].  Good luck

Comment: Step 1:  convert from text to some kind of object. Step 2: group and sum

Comment: Hi @MickyD. I am a beginner and I use SO to learn and put into practice everything I can find and that is right for me. For this case, unfortunately, I have found nothing that can help me. I didn't write any code because I just can't set it because I don't have the faintest idea of how to do it. If possible, I would be very happy to have help.

Comment: `unfortunately, I have found nothing that can help me` pfft, stack overflow and the internet is full of this stuff. research, reading a file line by line, and grouping

Comment: Hi, @John I am a beginner :(

Comment: Read [How to get started](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/).

Comment: Hi @TheGeneral, I found and read a lot but nothing that I can use to put my case into practice ... if you have a direct link I would be grateful

Comment: Have a look at list (data structure) and how to group https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results, probably then search how to read/write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Since your a beginner and learning, I'll give you a push in the right direction.

1. You can real all the lines in your file by `File.ReadLines`
2. You can split your lines into useful data with `string.split`, or *regex*
3. You can turn textual representation of numbers into numeric types using things like `int.Parse`
4. You can group by lists of data, using `GroupBy`
5. You can write the results (eventually) with `File.WriteAllLines`

---

**Further reading**

[File.ReadLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8)

> Reads the lines of a file.

[Enumerable.GroupBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8)

> Groups the elements of a sequence.

[String.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
>   character array.

Now this is a little more advanced, but a worth look at how to match patterns in a string

[Regex Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8)

This is a hugely popular technology and there is a wealth of information in all languages of how to use it

[Int32.Parse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.8)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent.

[File.WriteAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8)

> Creates a new file, writes one or more strings to the file, and then
>   closes the file.